# High application time in GC Log

Tags: java, garbage-collection

> Mystery in GC LOG - Application Time.

GC LOG contains more details and there is found "Application time" field and 83 Seconds was there. In that time server was active and suddenly a gap of 83 seconds found to be empty and there are no GC activities and no requests were accepted by the server and those requests were put in the TCP_Accept_Queue.

For 83 seconds the server didn't accepted and requests and already serving requests were hanged and then served after the 83 second gap.

> The GC LOG looked like this.
>
> ```
> 2019-08-27T19:37:08.328+0530: 7101.614: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0534706 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0004376 seconds
> 2019-08-27T19:38:31.713+0530: 7185.000: Application time: 83.3856673 seconds
> 2019-08-27T19:38:31.719+0530: 7185.005: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0054572 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0032875 seconds
> ```
>
> Need to know where exactly the 83 seconds spent by that application server.

Comment: **Application time: 83.3856673 seconds** shows the time for which application was actually running between GC pauses. You need to check other log files. Looks like those 83 seconds were not spent in GC

Comment: @Ivan thanks for your quick reply. 

I was clear that no GC will run in between the application time and it means there is no memory intensive operation done. but here the server is serving thousands of requests per minute and at that time 83 seconds of application time is surprising. Also all the threads were hanged during this application time mentioned in GC.

Is there any way or any specific log to identify the servers hanged state and why exactly this happens, except thread dump! because no thread dumps were available in that time :sad.

Comment: You need thread dump for that. You can also inspect code to check if there are pools of resources that block when no free resources in the pool are available